# Mediante programación deshabilitar opción guardar contraseña en gestor de contraseñas

Tags: javascript, c#, android, html5, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación en Android que usa el navegador "webView" para ver una url.

En esta url la primera pantalla tengo un formulario hecho con Visual Studio C# mas Html y Javascript. Necesito que cuando aparezca el formulario de credenciales y pase a la siguiente pantalla no pida guardar la contraseña en el gestor de contraseñas. Al menos que se pueda controlar cuando se vea en movil, en escritorio de PC no me importa que lo pida.

He probado en la aplicación Android poner lo siguiente pero a partir de la API 18 esta opción ya no es usable.

```
webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

También he probado mediante html poner la opción en la caja de texto autocomplete = "off" pero pide guardar la contraseña igualmente.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: No deberías necesitar hacer nada. La documentación dice que la función está obsoleta a partir de la API 18 porque guardar contraseñas no está soportado en WebView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings?hl=es-419#setSavePassword(boolean)

Comment: Pues me pide guardar contraseña con el siguiente mensaje "Save password to Google" y 2 botones "Not now" y "Save"

Comment: Como mencionan en el primer comentario, a partir de la API 18 no debería figurarte ese mensaje. De todas maneras, ¿Has probado controlar esto en otro dispositivo?

Comment: Que yo sepa eso sucede con Chrome. Webview solo puede darle a un gestor de contraseñas en tu sistema la posibilidad de guardarlas. A lo mejor es que te encuentras en una de las versiones en las que Chrome proveía el Webview. https://www.xda-developers.com/google-chrome-no-longer-webview-provider-android-10/amp/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas no tiene propiamente que ver con el código de la aplicación Android, tiene que ver con tu página, puedes [desactivar el autocompletado del formulario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) estableciendo el atributo que comentas en tu pregunta:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

pero en este caso no funciona para todos los navegadores por lo que puedes usar este truco, agregando:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

en realidad "nope" es un valor no valido que provoca no se intente en autocompletado, ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="autocomplete="nope"">
```

Comment: Lo he probado en PC con estos 2 navegadores que tengo instalados Firefox, Opera y no funciona

Comment: Comentas en tu pregunta que tienes una aplicación Android y ahí cargas l a página, debes probarla ahí. @Popularfan